# How to use lmap mappings in replacement text for substitution?

Tags: vim

I am using a keymap/lmap for creating language mappings. The help for `language-mapping` reads:

```
":lmap" defines a mapping that applies to:
- Insert mode
- Command-line mode
- when entering a search pattern
- the argument of the commands that accept a text character, such as "r" and
  "f"
- for the input() line
```

There is nothing said about substitution. For example, in `:%s/pattern/new_text/g`, if `new_text` needed an lmap to write easily, how do I do that?

Comment: umm the substitution is in command line mode. Which is one of the things listed. Do you have a problem with your mapping?

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me; does it work for you?

Comment: you need to press `ctrl-^` to enable your mapping in command-line mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same help you quoted. (`:h language-mapping`)

> When starting to enter a normal command line (not a search pattern) the mappings are disabled until a CTRL-^ is typed.

So all you need to do is type `<C-^>` to use the lang maps when in command line mode.

Comment: that would be the answer. :) +!

Comment: Thanks, did not notice this thing. Had been using these things for the first time.